# How to load images using metadata from the DropBox API

Tags: javascript, image, dropbox-api

I am getting just getting started with the DropBox API. Using POSTMAN, I have successfully retrieved an access token and have been able to list the metadata for files in my dropbox. I am trying to figure out how to use that metadata to load images on a web page using javascript. Is there an http call to generate a valid url to be used as the src parameter for an image or video element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `/media` endpoint: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#media. It generates anonymous-read URLs that work for up to four hours.

**UPDATE**

I'm not sure if you're using dropbox.js or not, but the method there is called [`makeUrl`](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/blob/stable/src/client.coffee#L767).

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I found it! The request name isn't the most intuitive, so I missed it looking through the documentation.

https://api.dropbox.com/1/media//