# Showing images from DropBox

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, dropbox-api

I've been trying for long time to show images that I have in Dropbox, I'm reading the files correctly, but in the view I'm not sure how to put the content of the `src` parameter of `image` . 
In my `controller` I'm getting a `SearchResult` and then I'm adding the results to a list of type `Metadata` This is the code:

```
Dropbox.Api.Files.SearchResult resultSearch = await client.Files.SearchAsync("/MyFiles/", ".jpg");

List<Dropbox.Api.Files.Metadata> list = new List<Dropbox.Api.Files.Metadata();

for (int i = 0; i < resultSearch.Matches.Count; i++)
{
    list.Add(resultSearch.Matches[i].Metadata);
}
```

Until now everything works great, even in the view the things works good, but how should I set the `src` parameter of the image I want to show from DropBox?
This code belongs to my view:

```
<img src="/Dropbox/MyFiles/MyImage.jpg" style="height:133px; width:213px;" class="highlight" alt="@temp">
```

I made a shortcut with relevant code only, I'm not hardcoding in my view but this is how the `src` parameter is getting filled, am I missing something? The image is not loading...

Comment: so what's the problem? You have the src defined there in your example. Is it not loading the image? Generally, if the image is hosted somewhere, you need the whole URL to the hosted image

Comment: @mmcrae That's correct it's not loading the image, I've tried in many different ways and it doesn't load it :(

Comment: @mmcrae I think I'm failing trying to get the whole url, I'm not sure yet how to get it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079407/how-to-load-images-using-metadata-from-the-dropbox-api?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23408261/image-not-being-retrieved-from-dropbox may be helpful. Either way, sounds like a Dropbox api question mostly. You need a full URL to the hosted image. Putting `Dropbox/MyFiles/MyImage.jpg` will have the website look on the server of your application, and look for those folders/files. Is the file hosted or is it on your server where the app is running?

Comment: http://cantonbecker.com/etcetera/2014/how-to-directly-link-or-embed-dropbox-images/

Comment: @mmcrae I will check those links immediately, the file is hosted in Dropbox not in my server side :)

Comment: You can use [GetTemporaryLinkAsync](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_GetTemporaryLinkAsync_1.htm) to get a temporary, direct link to a file, such as an image.

Comment: @Greg The only thing is that it expires after 4 hours, and I would like to have my application running online all the time, if you have any suggestion  let me know

Comment: In that case you can use [CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAsync](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Sharing_Routes_SharingUserRoutes_CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAsync_1.htm) with https://www.dropbox.com/help/201 .